# iPad as Home Hub: Option not available under iPad settings

Tags: ipad, icloud, homekit

I've given up on trying to make my once working Apple TV Home Hub respond again. So I logged the apple tv out of the appropriate iCloud account and decided I would make my iPad the HomeKit hub. Much to my chagrin, there does not seem to be a "Make iPod Home hub" option showing up under the iPad/Settings->Home (where all the instructions tell me to go an enable the iPad as the hub)

Per instructions, two-factor authentication, keychain, and Home are all enabled under the iPad/Settings//iCloud settings.

Suggestions are welcomed. Being unable to share lighting control with other household members is causing a great deal of irritation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but just saw it. You don't need a home hub to share your "home" with other users. Home hub is for automation.

I don't have a home hub and my wife and kid have access to my Apple home. In the Home app go to the top left house icon and add whomever you want to the people section.

Thanks

Comment: That's good information to know... but turns out I also wanted automations. I can't describe the turn of events that made things eventually work. I came across some anecdotal info about Apple IDs getting "blocked" by Apple (for whatever reason) and a call to Apple Tech support  making things work. Which is what I did. Hard to say if that is what fixed it.